# Что такое Binding и для чего он используется?

Tags: android, kotlin

Не могу разобраться что делает этот код :

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityPasswordlessBinding


binding = ActivityPasswordlessBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    setProgressBar(binding.progressBar)
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: @Komdosh а при чем тут ViewModel?

Comment: @Cypher тупанул :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*View Binding* в данном контексте имеет смысл связывания XML элементов `layout` с атрибутом `id` в соответствующие `View` объекты.

В вашем случае, технически это выглядит как генерация класса `ActivityPasswordlessBinding`, который будет соответствовать вашему `layout` в сгенерированном классе будут поля именами совпадающими с вашими `id` задекларированным в `layout`.

В частности запись: `binding.progressBar` означает, что в вашем `layout` видимо есть `ProgressBar` с идентификатором `progressBar`

Вопреки комментариям, не имеет прямого отношения к архитектуре [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). ViewModel прекрасно работает и без этого сахара. По сути это разновидность синтаксического сахара (ну чуть-чуть больше чем синтаксический сахар).

До появления *view binding* приходилось использовать различные ухищрения вроде аннотаций [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife). Сейчас уже рекомендовано с ButterKnife пересаживаться на view binding:

> Attention: This tool is now deprecated. Please switch to view binding. Existing versions will continue to work, obviously, but only critical bug fixes for integration with AGP will be considered. Feature development and general bug fixes have stopped.